# Can I make @RepositoryRestResource and JpaRepository user sensitive?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am having a typical application where a user can be in multiple groups, and of course, a group can hold multiple users:

```
User <-> GroupMember (ManyToMany) <-> Group
```

Also, a `GroupMember` can have other relations for example it can have an item which belongs to it - but only in the context of that particular group:

```
GroupMember <- OneToMany <- GroupMemberItem
```

---

My first question would be this: Let's say there is a `GroupRepository`

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "groups", path = "groups")
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<GroupEntity, Long> {
}
```

How would one fetch only the groups the user is actually assigned to and make it impossible for another user to access groups he is not.

Are `@RepositoryRestResource` / `JpaRepository` actullay designed for this? I am absolutely against writing `@Query` annotations where I end up writing queries which imho defy the whole purpose of why I would like to use them in the first place.

So if I told you

> "*I want http://localhost:8080/groups to return all the groups that the current logged in user is logged in*"

would you recommend me to go the `@RestController`, `@Service`, `@Repository` where I just implement the query by myself where might even end up switching up to something like jOOQ at this point or would you tell me to go for `@RepositoryRestResource` because there is a very easy way to accomplish that without having to write complex queries inside that Java `interface`?

---

The second question is kind of a follow up to the first one. Having said that a `GroupMember` can own one or many `GroupMemberItem`, I am having struggles to understand how `@RepositoryRestResource` can be used in order to fetch all the items from the logged in user in a selected group. Just writing the SQL query is not the problem but can this be done with `@RepositoryRestResource` / `JpaRepository`? If yes, how? I cannot find a single example and I've been looking for quite a while now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data JPA and spring-security: filter on database level (especially for paging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108543/spring-data-jpa-and-spring-security-filter-on-database-level-especially-for-pa)

Comment: Maybe my answer will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758549

Comment: @Cepr0 Thanks for the link but if I had to do it like this I would actually move to something like jOOQ - I wouldn't want to write my queries like that to be honest.